# Problem in setting up python debugger in VScode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

When ever I add breakpoint and run in debug mode I see this in my terminal:

PS C:\Users\fahad_Data_science>  & 'C:\Program Files\Python311\python.exe' 'c:\Users\fahad.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.16.0\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher' '9766' '--' 'c:\Users\fahad_Data_science\Trail.py'

However my launch.json file looks like :-

```
{
  // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
  // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    
    {
        "name": "Python: Attach using Process Id",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "attach",
        "processId": "${command:pickProcess}", 
        "justMyCode": true
    },
    {
      "name": "Python: Current File",
      "type": "python",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${file}",
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "justMyCode": true
    }

  ]
}
```

I tried to modify launch.json and write this commands in terminal
python -m debugpy --listen 5678 ./Test.py

Answer (score 0):

In VSCode debug tab, have you chosen the right config ? If you click on the drop-down list, [image]

you'll find the 2 configs that you have defined. Be sure to select the right one ("attach to process id" or "current file").